Web page slow loading possibly due to API request
I'd like to quickly explain the situation. Essentially, I've created a Livewire component that allows me to fetch data from a radio API to get songs. These songs change every 3 minutes, and I want to update my Blade view whenever the properties of this API change.
class TitleSong extends Component
{

    public $songTitle;
    public $songArtist;
    public $songImage;
    public $secondsTotal;
    public $secondsElapsed;
    public $elementToShow;
    public $remainingTime;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.title-song');
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->fetchSongData();
    }


    public function fetchSongData()
    {
        try{
         $response = Http::get('MY API');
        $data = $response->json(); 

       $this->songArtist = $data['song']['artist'];
        $this->secondsElapsed = $data['song']['seconds_elapsed'];
        $this->secondsTotal = $data['song']['seconds_total'];
        $this->songImage = $data['song']['art']; 
         $this->songTitle = $data['song']['title'];

        $remainingTime = $this->secondsTotal - $this->secondsElapsed;
        $this->remainingTime = $remainingTime; 

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        dd($th->getMessage());
    }
    }

}

And since this elements needs to be splitted in the whole document I made it possible with a new variable of "$elementToShow" This is the view:
<div wire:poll.{{$remainingTime}}="fetchSongData">
    @if ($elementToShow === 'songTitle')
        <h1 id="songTitle" style="color: var(--quaternary-color); font-weight: 600" class="text-4xl">{{$songTitle}}</h1>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'songArtist')
        <p id="songArtist" class="mt-2 ml-1" style="color: var(--quinary-color); font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px">{{$songArtist}}</p>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'secondsElapsed')
        <span id="secondsElapsed" class="current-time">0:00</span>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'secondsTotal')
        <span id="secondsTotal" class="total-time"> {{substr($secondsTotal, 0, 1) . ':' . substr($secondsTotal, 1, 2)}}</span>
    @elseif($elementToShow === 'songImage')
    <img style="position: absolute; left: 12%; top: 2%; border-radius:20px; z-index: 1" width="220px" height="200px" src="{{$songImage}}" />
    @endif
</div>

Now I would ask you if there's a better way to do this without using wire:poll or something else. Unfortunately this is causing me A LOT OF PAIN, because it affects so much the speed of my website. The website right now takes 5 seconds to load the HTML document.
I have no idea why this API call is taking me a long time to load, maybe it's the Livewire components, but I've tried doing a little optimization here and there and also using Laravel Debug.

How sure are you it's the API request? If you're sure I'll provide a write up that explains how you do this using lazy loading and such so you don't block the request while waiting for the API response

Continuing what @DylanMarriott, have you tried to load just the most basic things without the extra data? Both in controller and blade. Then compare the time loaded

Also you are trying to fetch data using $response = Http::get('MY API'); Did you check the response time for this too?

If the api is remote OR if the data only changes every few minutes, you shouldn't be adding this overhead to your website page load, this should be done on a cron job, e.g. every minute, or more frequently by utilizing sleep in the cron jobs.

I'd disagree Andy, I think it should be resolved on request.
You can add functionality to cache the Song so not every request requires to talk to the external API.
You then also have a 'time left' on the song in his code example, so we can look at when that cache entry was stored and what the time is when we receive the request and determine if we need to make a request again.
You could also just put it in the cache for the amount of time that the song had left too so you don't need to calc anything.
If we do cron etc we're adding external complexity and failure points.

Okay so there are some bad practices in the code provided so I will address that as well as the original problem you're looking for help with.
TLDR
You just need to either add the Lazy attribute to the class that is shipped with live wire, or in the parent view or on the route. Here's how to add the Lazy Attribute to the component.
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Lazy; // Import The Attribute
 
#[Lazy]
class SongTitle extends Component
{

public function mount() {
 // Resolve Song From API HERE
}

You should also not use the Boot method. This method is fired every time the User and the server communicate, as opposed to when the component is first rendered. You could end up asking the API for the song repeatedly for no reason, which will lock up and slow down your Application tremendously.
There are more details in the official documentation here - Livewire Lazy Loading
API Request Making Application Slow
To resolve this, we can Lazy Load the data for the song.
You probably shouldn't use Boot
The Boot Method is fired on every request between the client and the server. You could send many requests to this API Endpoint for the song data and block up requests when you don't need to get the song data, as nothing has changed for that to be required.
We should move this functionality to Mount instead. This will send the API Request for the song data only once, but you can still manually send another request if needed in the future.
You can read more about this in the Livewire Docs - Lifecycle Hooks
Why does the API Request Slow Down My App
When you browse a standard website that isn't a Single Page Application, your Web Browser (Google Chrome, for example) sends a request to a Web Server for a Page.
Sometimes, we encounter scenarios in which the server takes a while to respond, as it is occupied processing everything it needs to build this HTML File.
To combat this, we can use Lazy Loading, which is supported natively supported by Livewire. This is widely used throughout the internet to resolve the problem you're currently experiencing. Simply put, the server will respond with an HTML file, and Javascript will run on the client side in the web browser, which will handle getting this extra data and updating the page.
Livewire Specific Context
As Livewire somewhat emulates the experience you get from a non-monolithic SPA, your web browser can communicate back and forth with the server, and you might not be actually waiting for a request to complete. Instead, the Livewire Mount Or Render Method is taking some time to execute, and this needs to be finished before the Render Method returns the View.
How To Lazy Load In Livewire
In Livewire, the documentation covers Lazy Loading quite well here: Livewire - Lazy Loading
It's straightforward to implement this functionality although there is a few ways to achieve it. I can't imagine we don't want this Lazy Loading by default so the way I suggest this is done is by adding the Attribute to the component class as shown below:
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Lazy; // Import The Attribute
 
#[Lazy]
class SongTitle extends Component
{

Other Improvements
I'm unsure how close your example code is to your implementation, but there is no type hinting in place. We should probably separate the code more so we don't have classes and methods with multiple responsibilities.
Here's an improved example of your class that you can implement into your code base within a few minutes:
#[Lazy]
class TitleSong extends Component
{
    // set types on your variables
    public string $songTitle;
    public string $songArtist;
    public string $songImage;
    public int $secondsTotal;
    public int $secondsElapsed;
    public $elementToShow;
    public int $remainingTime;

    public function mount(): void
    {
    $this->resolveSong();
    }
    
    public function resolveSong(): void
    {
         // Logic for API stuff here
    }

Further improvements I would recommend looking into include creating a service to handle API communication for getting the Song Data.
I've created a GIST with some example classes suitable to the context you've provided. It doesn't go into a lot of detail but I'm hoping it's intuitive to understand so it's not too much of a problem.
Song Title Cleanup - Gist

Hey! I really appreciate your effort to explain this to help me! I used the #[Lazy] and this seems to be helped me very well but I wasn't satisfied yet. So my script now saves all of the API data inside a cache linked to Database. This data are flushed every seconds_total of the song and then a new request event it's triggered to make a new call and to put new data inside the cache and display them. I even used:
@persist .... @endpersist to render this component in all views without having to refresh him everytime I change route.

That sounds like a perfect solution, enjoy!
